# How many ways are there to cover an 8 by 8 square with 32 identical 2 by 1 rectangles?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recursion

How many ways are there to cover an 8 by 8 square with 32 identical 2 by 1 rectangles? This is different from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2346232/how-many-ways-are-there-to-cover-a-2-times-16-rectangle-with-2-times-2-2-t) because the layout can be recursive on two dimensions. I would start from a 2 by 2 square, then 3 by 3. However, from there I got lost how to write the recursion equation. Also, what if the area to cover is not a square, but a rectangle say 12 by 8?

Comment: Well, I just found a good answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358755/ways-to-fill-a-n-times-n-square-with-1-times-1-squares-and-1-times-2-recta?rq=1 . One of the answers offers a general solution to  m by n rectangle. It is much more involved than I thought with some serious research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $m\times n$ with $m,n$ odd, you cannot cover the rectangle with dominoes because there are an odd number of little squares and each domino covers two squares. For general $m\times n$ the sequence is given [here](http://oeis.org/A099390), and for the special case of $2n\times 2n$ [here](http://oeis.org/A004003). Unfortunately, there is no "nice" formula even in the $2n\times 2n$ case. The answer for the $8\times 8$ case that you asked is $12988816$.